# is it possible to draw an arrow from somewhere below ticks in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to draw a plot like this.

[image]

the tricky thing is the arrow from "z = -1.48" to x axis, which is under the ticks.

the piece of code shown below is my trying to draw that arrow.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,3))
x = np.linspace(-5,5,101)
x2 = np.linspace(-5,-1.5,101)
y = norm.pdf(x)
y2 = norm.pdf(x2)
t = ax.text(-3, 0.15, '-1.5')
plt.grid(True)
ax.plot(x, norm.pdf(x))
ax.fill_between(x2, 0, y2, color='r')
```

unfortunately, the part under ticks doesn't render.

[image]

is it possible to make the arrow under ticks shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `annotate`:

```
ax.annotate('1.5', 
            xy=(-1.5, 0), 
            xytext=(-1.5, -0.1), 
            ha='center', 
            va='center', 
            arrowprops={'arrowstyle': '->'})
```

This places text at `xytext` and draws an arrow from there to `xy`. `ha` and `va` refer to the alignment of the text based on those coordinates. If you don't pass `'center'`, the arrow and the text will be slightly misaligned. Lastly, passing `arrowprops` allows you to benefit from an inbuilt arrow style.

More information can be found in the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html).